# kustomization Error: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Image.images.newTag of type string

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

i have defined a kustomization.yaml in my CI/CD pipeline which will be updated by jenkins when a new build is done. The Update concerns the image tag of the builded and pushed image to the registry.
It is working quite good unless the image tag starts with a number in the value.

In that case (starting number in the image tag value) the kustomize tool generates an error:

```
kubectl kustomize ./
error: invalid Kustomization: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Image.images.newTag of type string
```

**Error example**
My kustomization.yaml contains in that case:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base/

replicas:
- name: demo-backend
  count: 1

images:
  - name: my-registry.domain.com/playground/demo-backend
    newTag: 839548e8
```

If the newTag variable starts with a character it is working fine.

**Working example**
My kustomization.yaml contains in that case:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base/

replicas:
- name: demo-backend
  count: 1

images:
  - name: my-registry.domain.com/playground/demo-backend
    newTag: e8395488
```

**What can i do to avoid this problem?**

I have tried to reproduce succesfully the error.
Found out, that the beginning of the value is the problem (number or character)

Comment: I think you need quotes for the value start with number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a regular "issue" not specific to Kustomize or even Yaml or Go: **`839548e8` is actually a number**. It's the notation of `839548 X 10^8`.

You need to enforce it is treated as a string for Kustomize. To do that, wrap it in quotes:

```yaml
newTag: '839548e8'
```

Comment: Hi,
yes this is the solution.
So for groovy or also in the Jenkinsfile i had do escape it with 3 times \\\"